# How to pass function to a dependent component repository?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have two repositories. The first repository is an actual app website. The other is a component library that contains all of the components that will be used inside the website.

I am trying to make it so all states (set up with pinia) are instantiated on the parent repository. Then the components inside the component library need to have access to these pinia objects.

How I'm currently thinking about it is that the interface would be defined in the component library then would be implemented on the parent repository.

This is how it's set up in my repositories right now.

```js
// Component Repository
// types/stores/cardJson.ts

export interface CardJsonStoreState {
  cardJson: CardJson;
}
  
export interface CardJsonStoreActions {
  update(cardJson: CardJson): void;
}
```

```js
// Parent Repository
// types/stores/cardJson.ts

export const useCardJsonStore = defineStore<'cardJson', CardJsonStoreState, {}, CardJsonStoreActions>('cardJson', {
  state: () => ({
    cardJson: []
  }),
  actions: {
    update(cardJson)  {
      this.cardJson = cardJson;
    }
  }
})
```

With this set up, accessing the state store on the parent repository is obviously very easy.

```js
import { useCardJsonStore } from './types/stores/cardJson';
useCardJsonStore().cardJson
```

But I'm not sure how to set it up so that the store is accessible to be able to do the same thing on the component repository.

Comment: Consider explaining your case. Why did you end up with such structure and what's the reason to keep the comps separate? Are these components being reused between multiple projects? If it's so, does each of them have its own unique store implementation? Generally you won't have such problem if you keep the stores and comps together, and you won't have it if you have both in separate packages that can be imported

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, the component library is being used in multiple projects. As I mentioned in the post, one is a website application. The other project will be a desktop application. They both will have the same state definitions that will be defined. I'm starting to consider the possibility of completely implementing the stores inside the component library but instantiating them in the main repository.

Comment: If the stores are common it makes perfect sense. Doing it the way you're doing now is still possible but requires another level of abstraction, `provide('cardJsonStore', useCardJsonStore())` in app root comp and `inject('cardJsonStore')` in components